# Diamond inheritance when only one object implements the base function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Yes, i've dealt with diamond inheritance before, but this time my problem seemed rather unique. I have an interface called IShaderResource which acts as the base class. I have another interface which derives from IShaderResource called IVertexBuffer. Then i have an implementation of the base interface called D3D11ShaderResource which derives from IShaderResource. Afterwards, i have an object called D3D11VertexBuffer which extends the D3D11ShaderResource and implements IVertexBuffer. So now my hierarchy looks like this.

```
                                IShaderResource
                                   /        \
                                  /          \
                         IVertexBuffer     D3D11ShaderResource
                                  \          /
                                   \        /
                                D3D11VertexBuffer
```

IShaderResource has only 1 pure virtual function. The part where this differs from normal diamond inheritance is that IVertexBuffer doesn't implement that function. It remains abstract, whereas D3D11ShaderResource does implement that function. When i virtually inherit IShaderResource to both derived classes, it still thinks I have an underfined abstract function. In order for my system to work, i need IVertexBuffer to be derived from IShaderResource. The implements would be in a dll that is dynamically loaded at the beginning of runtime, but will remain linked throughout the lifetime of the program. Therefore, any objects created from the dll anywhere can be accessed via the interface, but behind the interface, the types will be defined throughout the lifetime of the program. For example, if you have loaded the d3d11 library and create a vertex buffer, you get an IVertexBuffer ptr back that points to an instance of D3D11VertexBuffer and no other implemented vertex buffer implements are possible afterwards. This means that within the renderer, i can cast an IShaderResource to a D3D11ShaderResource knowing full well what it will be. (note * doing so outside the renderer would defeat the purpose of interfaces )

There are functions in my Renderer interface where i'd like to pass an IShaderResource like an IVertexBuffer and perform actions on the underlying D3D11VertexBuffer via only it's D3D11ShaderResource portion, while others would receive an IVertexBuffer and perform actions on the D3D11Vertexbuffer.  For that, i need to derive from IShaderResource to ensure that D3D11ShaderResource is a complete type of IShaderResource, while also having D3D11VertexBuffer inherit from both IVertexBuffer and D3D11ShaderResource.

I'm pushing 4000 lines of code here so i'll just post the offending excerpts.

IShaderResource

```
class IShaderResource
{
public:
    struct INIT_DESC
    {
        SYNC_USAGE usage;
    };

public:
    // virtual destructor for derived classes
    virtual ~IShaderResource() {}

    // the resource usage hint
    virtual IRenderUtility::SYNC_USAGE GetUsageType() = 0;
};
```

IVertexBuffer

```
class IVertexBuffer : 
    public virtual IShaderResource
{
public:
    struct INIT_DESC : public IShaderResource::INIT_DESC
    {
        const void * Data;
        unsigned int ByteWidth;
        unsigned int ByteStride;
    };

public:
    // virtual destructor for derived classes
    virtual ~IVertexBuffer() {}

    // the resource usage hint
    virtual IRenderUtility::SYNC_USAGE GetUsageType() = 0;
};
```

D3D11ShaderResource

```
class D3D11RenderUtility::D3D11ShaderResource : 
    public virtual IRenderUtility::IShaderResource
{
public:
    struct INIT_DESC
    {
        IRenderUtility::SYNC_USAGE usage;
        ID3D11ShaderResourceView * resourceView;
    };

public:
    // default constructor
    D3D11ShaderResource(INIT_DESC & desc) : 
        m_Usage(desc.usage),
        m_ResourceView(desc.resourceView)
        {}

    // virtual destructor for derived classes
    virtual ~D3D11ShaderResource() {}

    // obtains the resource usage hint
    IRenderUtility::SYNC_USAGE GetUsageType() {return m_Usage;}

    // used to obtain the resource view of the object
    ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> GetResourceView() const {return m_ResourceView;}

protected:
    IRenderUtility::SYNC_USAGE m_Usage;
    ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> m_ResourceView;
};
```

D3D11VertexBuffer

```
class D3D11RenderUtility::D3D11VertexBuffer : 
    public IRenderUtility::IVertexBuffer ,
    public D3D11RenderUtility::D3D11ShaderResource
{
public:
    struct INIT_DESC : 
        public D3D11ShaderResource::INIT_DESC
    {
        ID3D11Buffer * buf;
    };

private:
    // disable copy constructor 
    D3D11VertexBuffer(const D3D11VertexBuffer & buf);

    // disable assignment operator
    void operator=(const D3D11VertexBuffer & buf);  

public:
    // default constructor
    D3D11VertexBuffer(INIT_DESC & desc) :
        D3D11ShaderResource(desc),
        m_Buffer(desc.buf)
        {}

    // virtual destructor for derived classes
    virtual ~D3D11VertexBuffer() {}

    // used to obtain the d3d11 vertex buffer pointer
    ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> GetBuffer() const {return m_Buffer;}

private:
    ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_Buffer;
};
```

IRenderUtility::SYNC_USAGE is a simple enum further up the framework, and ComPtr is a little smart wrapper i made to automatically release com pointers. Other than that, the rest is pretty apparent.

btw, the actual error is this:
`error C2259: 'SYNC::D3D11RenderUtility::D3D11VertexBuffer' : cannot instantiate abstract class
2>          due to following members:
2>          'SYNC::IRenderUtility::SYNC_USAGE SYNC::IRenderUtility::IVertexBuffer::GetUsageType(void)' : is abstract`

SYNC is the namespace that all of this is in.

Comment: Maybe needs a `using D3D11RenderUtility::D3D11ShaderResource::GetUsageType;` in `D3D11VertexBuffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're using here is what the language definition calls "dominance". If only one of your two intermediate classes overrides a virtual function defined in the virtual base, then that definition applies in the derived class as well. As @chuex said, you need to remove the redundant  declaration in IVertexBuffer, because that breaks the premise for dominance to apply.

Adding redundant code for readability or any other reason is usually a bad idea, if only because it makes maintenance harder. Here it defeats what your class hierarchy is trying to do.

Comment: interesting. I didn't bother removing it before because i was sure i'd already tried it. Then i removed it, and it compiles after i was banging my head against a wall trying to find a more complicated solution . this victory is bittersweet -_- . Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I really do like redeclaring inherited virtual functions so that one look at an object will tell you all the functions that it has available to use/override in itself and it's base. Is there any way to do that here without dominance being 'nullified', or do i resort to MOAR comments?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis - you can always use the Class Viewer in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to remove the declaration of `GetUsageType` in `IVertexBuffer`. It seems redundant to have it there AND in the base `IShaderResource`.

Comment: It might be redundant, but it shouldn't hurt anything.